# JSON stringify not working for array of json objects

Tags: node.js, json

The following code fails on requiring the JSON file in node after using `JSON.stringify(...)` to write it out. When checking the file, there are no weird characters at the end, and the last JSON object closes properly with `}` then `]` to end the array.

```
fs.writeFile('marketData.json', JSON.stringify(costArray), 'utf8', function(){
    console.log("Market data written to file");
});
//in different function now
const marketPrices = require('./marketData');

(node:9484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: C:\Users\Ethan\hpsite\hpstore\server\marketData.json: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Comment: can you share marketData.json

Comment: You're not waiting for the file to be written before `require()`'ing it, are you?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the line that attempts to read the JSON is being executed before the file is actually written.

The callback function (where you write the confirmation message to the console), is when you know the file is written. If you were to re-write it as follows, you should see the expected result:

```
fs.writeFile('marketData.json', JSON.stringify(costArray), 'utf8', function(){

    // Now we're sure the file has been written, so we can read it.
    console.log("Market data written to file");
    const marketPrices = require('./marketData');
});

// Anything here will get executed *immediately* after you *start* writing the file,
// which does not guarantee the file has actually been written yet (and in most cases,
// it won't have been).
```